# TFS 2013, Exception TF10144: 'F' is not a supported version specification type

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

- I have recently upgraded Team Foundation Server from version 2012 to 2013 with Update 3.
- I have configured a build definition using a custom build template that derived from TfvcTemplate.12.xaml.
- The build number format is set to $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.rr).

**Upon queueing a build the follwing exception is thrown and the build fails:**

Exception Message: TF10144: 'F' is not a supported version specification type. (type BuildServerException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildWebService4.UpdateBuilds(BuildUpdateOptions[] updateOptions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetail.Save()
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: TF10144: 'F' is not a supported version specification type. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: 
Exception Stack Trace:

An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\loinc-build\Drop\Relma-Daily-Ancillaries\2014.10.02.08\Logs' is denied.
 An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\loinc-build\Drop\Relma-Daily-Ancillaries\2014.10.02.08\Logs' is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my attempt at a work around on a different problem caused this error. The default build template for TFS 2013 is throwing the following exception:

Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "GetVersion".
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'String'.

As a workaround, I tried to change the parameter for TfGetSources named VersionOverride to GetVersion.ToString().

The above error was resolved once I rolled-back my failed workaround.